# ServerSocket not working for me on android

Tags: java, android, networking, serversocket

So I'm creating an online game for the android and. ever the over achiever, I've found a way to make it more complicated then it should be. So I have one server which which is the login server. It listens for a connection from the android device. Once it gets it accepts username and passowrd, checks to make sure they're valid and then sends the devices ipaddress and port number to the game server. The android device then listens for a connection from the game server.

All of this is working until the game server tries to connect to the device. At that point it hangs for a while then the game server throws this Exception: "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond [deviceIP]:[port]".

There's no mention of the attempt to connect in LogCat. I'm using ServerSock to listen for the game server connection by the way. I initialize it to port zero then call getLocalPort() to get the port it bound to to send off to the login server.

I've tried everything I can think of and I can't get it to work.

Comment: Is your game server on the internet? or on a local network with your device? If it is on the internet I don't think your game server is going to be able to connect to the device that way because the device IP address is not going to be publicly accessible on the internet. Also it may help if you can edit your question and include the code that you are using to listen for connection from the game server.

Comment: @FoamyGuy I suspected that. Seems like a pretty secure setup as far as preventing DDoS attacks and unauthorized connections on the game server, but if it can't be done, it can't be done. My game server is using the internet.

Comment: I would change the architecture. Instead of having the login server tell the game server to connect to the client, I would have the login server connect to the game server and proxy the existing client connection between the client and the game server. Then the game server doesn't have to create any connections at all, just accept them.

Comment: @EJP I don't know... seems like the login server would be a huge bottleneck in that set up. There can be more than one game server and if all traffic has to come through the login server it could get overloaded.

Comment: Web proxies do that all the time.